# (Ubuntu 14.04.2) Unity will not load on Dell Inspiron 531s with Nvidia GeForce 6150SE graphics

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, login, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 531s desktop computer. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on it, but I can only install it from USB when I go to the "Install Ubuntu" option and not the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option because nothing will show up. When I boot up Ubuntu, I can log in, but after that, there is only the background and my mouse and nothing else. I have tried all kinds of things from other threads, but they have not worked. I have also tried installing `nvidia-current` and `nvidia-current-updates` to no avail. None of the commands from the mentioned thread works for me. Also, I can boot into recovery mode, but only if I don't have the Nvidia driver. And I haven't been able to do a normal boot at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue by going into the Ubuntu recovery mode and running `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command:

`sudo apt-get install gdm -y`

And selecting gdm as your default Display Manager. Reboot.

Comment: I installed GDM and it will not even load completely and if it does it freezes. I went into the Ubuntu recovery mode and now I can get in the desktop at low resolution, but I don't know what to do next.